# How to pass a value as a key name in an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, key-value

I want to pass a key name to a dictionary but I am unable to do so. For instance,

```
let x=[]
let key_names=['a.b.c','g.h.i'] //these can be any values which is a result of another computation
x.push({key_names[0]:1,key_names[1]:2})
console.log(x)
//Expected output - [{'a.b.c':1,'g.h.i':2}]
```

But this gives me an error -

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

How do I achieve the expected output?

Answer (score -1):

For computed property, you should wrap it in a bracket `[]`

```js
let x=[]
let key_names=['a.b.c','g.h.i'] //these can be any values which is a result of another computation
x.push({[key_names[0]]:1, [key_names[1]]:2})
console.log(x)
```

#### References

[Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#syntax)